# Updating column in table to equal another column in same table WHERE NOT syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have two columns where I'm trying to iron out some mixed data. The two columns that have mixed data are `industry` and `theme`. There are placeholder columns to hold the sussed out data called `industry_temp` and `theme_temp`.

Since there are many more `theme`'s than `industry`'s, I'm trying to do the following 2 steps, with only the first one working as I had expected:

1) Set industry-temp table to equal all industry types that were mixed into the theme category

```
UPDATE my_table SET industry_temp=theme WHERE theme='industry_type_1' OR theme='industry_type_2' OR theme='industry_type_3' OR theme='industry_type_4';
```

2) Set theme-temp table to equal all theme types when the theme type does not equal an industry type.

```
UPDATE my_table SET theme_temp=industry WHERE industry <> 'industry_type_1' OR industry <> 'industry_type_2' <> OR industry <>'industry_type_3' OR industry <> 'industry_type_4';
```

Step 2 is not respecting the `<>` operator and adding ALL values from the industry column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NOT IN`, the logic is much simpler to follow:

```
UPDATE my_table
    SET theme_temp=industry
    WHERE industry NOT IN ('industry_type_1', 'industry_type_2', 'industry_type_3', 'industry_type_4');
```

Comment: This is definitely the most straightforward solution, and easy to follow. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `AND` instead of `OR`

but for simplicity `NOT LIKE 'industry_type_%'` should achieve your goal.

Comment: This achieved the desired result, thanks for fix. The other solution offered made the query a bit easier to follow.